# Filtrar arquivos pela sua extensão(xml, rar, docx.....)

Tags: java, xml, algoritmo, netbeans, java-8

Boa Tarde,
Estou com um algorítimo que pegas todos os aquivos de um diretório x, e faz a leitura dos mesmo, porem esses arquivos tem que ser XML, e as vezes aparecem uns arquivos RAR, ai na hora de ler dar erro pois não consegue entrar no arquivo, teria alguma coisa que eu posso fazer para que ele leia é somente os XML, descartando os demais arquivos?

Aqui ele le o localXML.xml, onde é informado onde esta salvo os outros aquivos e logo depois é cria um vetor com o nome de todos os arquivos, seja ele XML ou nao.

```
// realiza a leitura do xml para identificar o local onde esta os XMLs salvos
    File lerxml = new File("C:\\FTP\\arquivos\\localXML.xml");
    xml = builder.parse(lerxml);
    NodeList locais = xml.getElementsByTagName("localXML");
    e = (Element) locais.item(0);
    String local = e.getTextContent();

    // ja com a identificação feita é criado um vetor onde é recebido o nome de tds os xmls
    File diretorio = new File(local);
    arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();
    int i; // contador primeiro for
    int j; // contador segundo for
    int a = 0; // contador de linhas geradas
```

o que eu gostaria é que ele pega-se somente os XML desconsiderando os demais arquivos, ou, na hr de tentar ler o mesmo, ele verifique se é XML ou nao, se nao for ele nem executa a leitura.

Código completo

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ftp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 *
 * @author samuel.silva
 */
public class FTP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory fabrica = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = fabrica.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xml;
        Element e;
        File arquivos[];

        // realiza a leitura do xml para identificar o local onde esta os XMLs salvos
        File lerxml = new File("C:\\FTP\\arquivos\\localXML.xml");
        xml = builder.parse(lerxml);
        NodeList locais = xml.getElementsByTagName("localXML");
        e = (Element) locais.item(0);
        String local = e.getTextContent();

        // ja com a identificação feita é criado um vetor onde é recebido o nome de tds os xmls
        File diretorio = new File(local);
        arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();
        int i; // contador primeiro for
        int j; // contador segundo for
        int a = 0; // contador de linhas geradas

        //entra em um arquivo por vez pegando os dados
        for (i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
            // realiza a leitura para saber quantos dados tem no xml atual
            xml = builder.parse(arquivos[i]);
            xml.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList quant = xml.getElementsByTagName("esn");
            int k = quant.getLength();

            // le tds os dados do xml atual
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                a++; // contador

                //pegas a informação referente aos Playload
                NodeList payloads = xml.getElementsByTagName("payload");
                e = (Element) payloads.item(j);
                String payload = e.getTextContent();
                System.out.println(payload);

                //pegas a informação referente aos esn
                NodeList aparelhos = xml.getElementsByTagName("esn");
                e = (Element) aparelhos.item(j);
                String esn = e.getTextContent();
                System.out.println(esn);

                //pegas a informação referente aos timeStamp
                NodeList timeStamps = xml.getElementsByTagName("stuMessages");
                e = (Element) timeStamps.item(0); // diferente da capturas anterior, o timeStamp é unico dentro de cada arquivo
                String timeStamp = e.getAttribute("timeStamp");
                System.out.println(timeStamp);

                //realiza a criação de varios csn, onde cada csv é referente a um modem(esn)
                File arquivo = new File("C:\\Ler XML\\resultado.csv");
                arquivo.createNewFile(); //Caso voce queira criar um novo arquivo a partir de cada formulario use esse comando
                try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true)) {
                    //salva as informações no mesmo
                    fw.write(payload + ";" + esn + ";" + timeStamp + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
        // contador de linhas Geradas
        System.out.println("Numero de Linhas Geradas: " + a);
    }

}
```

----------------------------Atualização 2 ---------------------------------------

Fiz o que comentou Porem esta apresentando um erro agora, segue o Print
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução simples é verifica a extensão do arquivo dentro do seu `for`:

```
//entra em um arquivo por vez pegando os dados
for (i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
    //verifica se é um arquivo xml
    if (arquivos[i].getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")) {
```

Dessa forma somente os arquivos de extensão *xml* serão parseados.

---

Uma outra solução, seria verifica a extensão do arquivo, porém utilizando a classe `FilenameFilter`, importamos a classe para utilização:

```
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
```

E no método `listFiles`, instanciámos a mesma criando o método `accept`, filtrando assim somente os arquivos de extensão *xml*:

```
arquivos = diretorio.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");
    }
});
```

Comment: Realizei uma Atualização 2 na minha pergunta

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa e descobri que o erro pode ser do XML que esta faltando alguma coisa.

Comment: Porem estou falando de 3180 xml, não tem como eu localizar qual esta com o problema, no caso eu teria que ignorar  ele na hr de rodar o algorítimo, dar um jeito de ler. todo dia vou ter essa base de arquivos

Comment: Tente fazer um tratamento de exceção durante o parser, isso já vai fazer deixar de dar erro e você ainda consegue descobrir qual o XML que está incorreto.